# uva 10189 Minesweeper

Tags: algorithm

Here's the link to the problem: http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=13&page=show_problem&problem=1130

This is my code and it works perfectly; however, it gives wrong answer whenever I submit it. Does anybody know why?

NOTE: I pad the matrix with 2 extra rows and columns so that when I'm checking the left of the first column or the bottom of the last row, I don't get an error.

```
public class Main {
public void convert(char[][] maze, int fieldNum) {
    if (fieldNum != 1)
        System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Field #" + fieldNum + ":");
    int n = maze.length;
    int m = maze[0].length;
    char[][] result = new char[n][];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result[i] = new char[m];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            result[i][j] = '0';
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < m - 1; j++) {
            if (maze[i][j] == '*') {
            this.fill(result, i, j);
        }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < m - 1; j++) {
            System.out.print(result[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
private void fill(char[][] maze, int i, int j) {
    if (maze[i-1][j-1] != '*')
        maze[i-1][j-1] += 1;
    if (maze[i][j-1] != '*')
        maze[i][j-1] += 1;
    if (maze[i+1][j-1] != '*')
        maze[i+1][j-1] += 1;
    if (maze[i-1][j] != '*')
        maze[i-1][j] += 1;
    maze[i][j] = '*';
    if (maze[i+1][j] != '*')
        maze[i+1][j] += 1;
    if (maze[i-1][j+1] != '*')
        maze[i-1][j+1] += 1;
    if (maze[i][j+1] != '*')
        maze[i][j+1] += 1;
    if (maze[i+1][j+1] != '*')
        maze[i+1][j+1] += 1;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Main sweeper = new Main(); 
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = null;
    int fieldNum = 1;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] xy = line.trim().split("\\s+");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(xy[0]);
        int m = Integer.parseInt(xy[1]);
        if (n == 0 && m == 0)
            break;
        n += 2;
        m += 2;
        char[][] maze = new char[n][];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            maze[i] = new char[m];
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
            line = reader.readLine();
            for (int j = 1; j < n - 1; j++) {
                maze[i][j] = line.charAt(j - 1);
            }
        }
        sweeper.convert(maze, fieldNum);
        fieldNum++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If it gives you a wrong answer, then it's not working perfectly. Also, people aren't going to debug your code for you--do you have a specific question you think can be answered here?

Comment: I dont know why uva gives RE but Programming challenges gives WA.

Comment: @simchona, RE = Runtime Error, WA = Wrong Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of telling others to debug a long code, you can use [this site](http://uvatoolkit.com/problemssolve.php) to generate output for given input for a UVa problem and compare with your solution. It supports around 1500 problems.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, Minesweeper, is also on URL http://www.programming-challenges.com/pg.php?page=downloadproblem&probid=110102&format=html

If you are getting "Presentation error", make sure empty lines in output are only between Field #n and Field#n+1. There should be no empty lines before or after.

Here is how provided 'Sample Output' must be displayed in bash:

```
$ java Main <input
Field #1:
*100
2210
1*10
1110

Field #2:
**100
33200
1*100
$
```

Notice single empty line before Field #2: line.